Pure-CSS perspective parallax effect only works on Firefox and not on Chrome or Safari
I tried making a webpage where backgrounds scroll a bit slower than the text content, giving an illusion of a 3d scene, but my method only works on firefox. On chrome and safari any transform property cancels the effect of background-attachment:fixed. Why doesn't it work on other browsers? What changes could be made to make it more compatible?
This is what I tried:
https://codepen.io/brch_/pen/JjQmPOr
Expected result: perspective parallax result while scrolling.
Actual result: effect works on firefox, does not work on chrome and safari.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You may need to be aware that background-attachment fixed has problems on IOS

You should remove the transform property from you title::before because when you add it the background image starts behaving as if it is attached to the transformed element rather than the viewport, breaking the parallax effect. Hope that helps.


.t1.title::before {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659691273337-99bd8d0630fc?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MjUyMTU4MzJ8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85);
}
.t1.color {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
.t2.title::before {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722325009084-6bfc230f0860?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MjUyMTU4MzJ8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85);
}
.t2.color {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.t3.title::before {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1659691273337-99bd8d0630fc?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MjUyMTU4MzJ8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85);
}
.t3.color {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
.t4.title::before {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722325009084-6bfc230f0860?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MjUyMTU4MzJ8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: TT-Drugs;
  src: url(/static/font/TT\ Drugs\ Regular.otf);
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "TT-Drugs";
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100lvh;
  min-width: 100lvw;
}
#navbar {
  z-index: 5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 5lvh;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
#navbar a {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.title {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100lvh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
}
.title::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
.color {
  height: 10lvh;
}
.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/index.less'|compile %}" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.6.0/css/all.css"
        />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrap">
            <!-- t1 -->
            <div class="title t1">
                <h1>T1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="t1 color"></div>
            <!-- t2 -->
            <div class="t2 title">
                <h1>T2</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="t2 color"></div>
            <!-- t3 -->
            <div class="t3 title" >
                <h1>T3</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="t3 color"></div>
            <!-- t4 -->
            <div class="t4 title">
                <h1>T4</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



